# Tricky sql to select distinct user

Tags: sql, sql-server

given the following data/tabel:

```
User|Value
A 1
A 1
B 3
B 1
A 1
A 3
A 3
B 1
B 1
A 1
B 1 
B 1
A 3
A 3
B 1
```

Here I want to pick out those users who have alternated the Value column more than once.
Eg. Here B is not a problem as it changes only once, A on the other hand changes often and I want a sql select that returns A.

I have not found any examples on how to do this! :(

Comment: Is there any additional row to the table? Do you mean "alternating" simply by the insert order?

Comment: There is nothing to order the rows. There is no implicit order in SQL Server or SQL generally or in storage or in insert order. There is not enough information in the table to do what you want. Edit: -1 because it was upvoted too...

Comment: Do you have any other column in that table? An id? A creation date?

Comment: This is a licensing table. I want to see those who change their licenses on/off to always be beyound their companys allowed number of licensens. They pay for a certain amount of license, but those licenses are per user name, but some customers put some of their users to inactive to allow other to user their licenses. So I want to find those how manipulate their userlist often

Comment: The columns i have: UserId, UserName, Value

Comment: After some further thinking I think that you can't do this with a single SELECT-statement. You'll need some stored procedure to loop through all records of one user and check whether or not the `Value` changes more than once. Then you can return a list of users to the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u1.UserName
FROM Users u1
INNER JOIN Users u2 ON u1.UserName = u2.UserName
INNER JOIN Users u3 ON u1.UserName = u3.UserName
WHERE u1.Value <> u2.Value
AND u1.UserID < u2.UserID
AND u2.Value <> u3.Value
AND u2.UserID < u3.UserID
```

Assuming your table is called "Users", of course :)

Comment: When you change your inner join to join on UserID it might work

Comment: That's what I was doing before, but having u1.UserID = u2.UserID and u1.UserID < u2.UserID in one query is not a very good start :)

Comment: I do agree this is not the prettiest query I have ever seen, though.

Comment: I can imagine :) Maybe an index on UserName could help?

Comment: (and on UserID and on Value, by the way)

Comment: Self join is a really hard operation to sql server.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table(user_id char(1), val tinyint)

insert into @t
select 'A', 1
union all
select 'A', 1
union all
select 'B', 3
union all
select 'B', 1
union all
select 'A', 1
union all
select 'A', 3
union all
select 'A', 2
union all
select 'A', 1
union all
select 'B', 1
union all
select 'B', 1
union all
select 'A', 1

select user_id, count(distinct val)
from @t
group by user_id
having count(distinct val) > 2
```

Comment: OP said: "Here B is not a problem as it changes only once, A on the other hand changes often and I want a sql select that returns A." Therefore, shouldn't the predicate instead be `having count(distinct val) > 2`?